# Excel Formatting data Table

Tags: excel, windows, excel-2010

I am using Excel 2010. I have a pivot chart which is a bar graph with a data table. For all other pivot charts I right clicked and selected sort a to z to have the bars sorted by year. When the pivot chart has a data table I can't seem to be able to sort a to z.

How do you sort a bar chart going year to year. In order of year which has a data table because I can't right click on the horizontal axis to filter the years in order.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to sort the data it referenced to have my pivot chart sorted by year.